# Why doesn't WPF ComboBox reflect properly the bound value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ComboBox whose properties ItemsSource and SelectedValue are bound to a model. Sometimes, the model needs to adjust the selected item to a different one, but when I do it in the model, the model value is not being reflected in the View, even though the SelectedValue is properly set (checked both with snoop and in SelectionChanged event handler).

To illustrate the problem, here is a simple xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
      <ComboBox Height="25" Width="120" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}" SelectedValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleValues}" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
      int m_selectedValue = 2;
      Dictionary<int, string> m_possibleValues = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "one" }, { 2, "two" }, { 3, "three" }, {4,"four"} };

      public int SelectedValue
      {
         get { return m_selectedValue; }
         set 
         {
            if (value == 3)
            {
               m_selectedValue = 1;
            }
            else
            {
               m_selectedValue = value;
            }
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedValue"));
         }
      }
      public Dictionary<int, string> PossibleValues
      {
         get { return m_possibleValues; }
         set { m_possibleValues = value; }
      }


      public MainWindow()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   }
}
```

I Expected the behaviour to be as follows:

1. Initially, two is selected
2. Select "one" -> ComboBox displays "one"
3. Select "two" -> ComboBox displays "two"
4. Select "three" -> ComboBox displays "**one**"
5. Select "four" -> ComboBox displays "four"

However, in #4, "three" is displayed. Why? The value in the model was changed to 1 ("one"), but the View still displays 3 ("three").

I have found a workaround by explicitly updating the binding target in a SelectionChanged event handler, but this seems wrong. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't the ComboBox display the current state of the model? It may not be intuitive, but it is the right thing to display. This is actually a simplified example. The actual use case is a bit more complicated, but it boils down to the same issue

Comment: Have you tried making the SelectedValue explicitly Two-way? {Binding Path=SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: @JacobProffitt Mode is TwoWay by default, but I just tried to set it explicitly and the problem persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you select an item, the binding engine will update the model, and will ignore any `PropertyChanged` for the property it just changed during the time it's invoking the property setter. If it didn't, things could potentially go into an infinite loop.

The system assumes that the setter won't change the value it was passed. The workaround here is simple: use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` or set `IsAsync=True` on your binding to get the behavior you're looking for. However, I personnaly **strongly discourage** you to do this. Not only because it introduces a whole bunch of new problems related to timings, but mainly because it's a workaround to a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Simply don't do this. It's not only applying to WPF: anything changing a setter could expect that the value it just set was correctly set is no exception is thrown. Changing the value inside the setter is counter intuitive and could bite you later. Plus, it can be really disturbing for the user of your application to see the combobox ignoring its selection.

If you don't like the value being passed, throw an exception and use `Binding.ValidatesOnExceptions` to tell WPF that it's expected. If you don't want the user to select this value, don't put it inside the list in the first place. If the item shouldn't be available conditionally because of other business rules, filter the list dynamically or apply triggers.

Comment: `IsAsync=True` works. Reading the description, I'm not sure why it does as it's not meant for this but it does :) . You mentioned that you discourage this implementation. Any suggestions what I can do instead? The actual use case is this: I have a predefined number of value profiles that I have to try to approximate. This maps really well with a combobox paradigm as the user should select one of the predefined values. However, there are certain cases when I cannot reach the selected value, so not to mislead the user, I like to change the value to an "in-between" value.

Comment: To add to the above comment, another way of thinking about what this setter does is to think of it as a "wish". As in, "I wish to set this value, but if you can't, approximate as close as possible"

Comment: I disagree. The whole point of having a "setter" property is to protect the backing field (which could be made public). The property SHOULD be performing checks and validation on the value and ensuring that it is valid. If it is not, throwing an exception is not always a practical solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have had persistent problems with proper updating of the control when binding to the `SelectedValue` and/or `SelectedItem` properties of a `ComboBox` control.

To solve this, I had to bind to the `SelectedIndex` property instead.  It was more hassle to deal with an 'index' property in my ViewModel, but it solved the problem with the `ComboBox` not updating.

Comment: I actually tried all SelectedValue, SelectedItem, and SelectedIndex with same result.